# Node.js how to find and stop socket connection

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io in one of express route to populate data from server and send it to on client with different event names, firstsocket and secondsocket.

```
var io
router.get('/start', function(req, res, next) {
    io = req.app.get('socketio');
    var socketlist = [{name:"firstsocket"},{name:"secondsocket"}]
    for (var key in socketlist){ 
        myInterval = setInterval(function(){
         JsonObj.marks = socketlist[key].name+' '+parseInt(Math.random()*100);
         io.emit(socketname, JsonObj);  
        }, 2000); 
    }   
});
```

it is working and i can see the data on client console for these to socket events. Now i want to stop one of the socket event based on user button click. I am not getting idea to list and stop sockets.

```
router.get('/stop', function(req, res) {
    if(req.socketname=='firstsocket') {
     //stop and destroy firstsocket
    }
    if(req.socketname=='secondsocket') {
     //stop and destroy secondsocket
    }
    res.redirect('/');
 });
```

please suggest, how to identify and stop one socket session out of multiple sessions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the `socket.id` information of each socket within your

`var socketlist = [{name:"firstsocket"},{name:"secondsocket"}];` array,

then you would be able to close a socket connection by doing;

```
io.sockets.sockets[socketlist[req.socketname].socket_id].disconnect(true);
```

Though, I would recommend you to check if

```
io.sockets.sockets[socketlist[req.socketname].socket_id]
```

returns `undefined` before accessing it's `disconnect` property.

If you try to access `disconnect` property of an already closed socket, the code above will return `undefined` and you will have an error thrown  saying

```
"Can't access the property disconnect of undefined"
```

Final code should be something like this;

```
if (io.sockets.sockets[socketlist[req.socketname].socket_id]) {
    io.sockets.sockets[socketlist[req.socketname].socket_id].disconnect(true);
}
```

You can get the `socket.id` information of a socket on the initial connection to the server.

I'd advise you to move your `io` decleration out of the `route` and declare it like this with your socket list;

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var socketlist = [], first_socket_connected = false;
```

The server variable should be your express server.

Then, use the code below to receive socket connections and push to your socket list;

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socketlist.push({name: first_socket_connected ? "secondsocket" : "firstsocket", id: socket.id});
    first_socket_connected = true;
});
```

Comment: I got error "Cannot read property 'socket_id' of undefined" with the solution suggested. I took socketlist declaration out of route('/start') function but same result. Anyway, why there is need to add socket_id when we have "name" for identifications?

Comment: I forgot to add first_socket_connected = true; I've added it now. Was that the reason your code got broken?

Comment: Thanks @Umit, it worked now. but i had to make a bit change in close. I wrote, for (var key in socketlist){
 if (socketlist[key].name == req.query.name){
 io.sockets.sockets[socketlist[key].id].disconnect(true); 
 }
} . And it worked :-)

Comment: I am glad if I helped! Have a nice day.